# How to cast to NSError from this [value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using external component to connect to SOAP service. When I receive result it is returned as object `value`, which can contain `NSError` or resulting object.

In case of an error I want to extract code and message of the error. How to cast `value` to NSError?

I receive `[value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]` to check if an error is returned.

Comment: Is anything wrong with `NSError *error = (NSError *)value` when your test returns `YES`?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing wrong with that convention, 10x for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    NSError *error = (NSError *)value;
    NSLog(@"It didn't work: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    // returned object
}
```